# How to get the content of the class attribut with Python/XPATH?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

Is it possible to get the content of the class attribut and how to implement this?

Comment: Do you mean the script associated with the class? or the class name it-self?

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The class name it-self.

```
    tform = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id = 'table-type-1']/tbody/tr/td[@class ='form col_form']/div/a[@class]")
```

Print(tform.text) returns the correct number of hits, but strings are empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
linkClass = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id = 'table-type-1']/tbody/tr/td[@class ='form col_form']/div/a").get_attribute('class')
print(linkClass)
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Check with this updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried with this updated answer `find_element_by_xpath` should not give that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    linkClass = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id = 'table-type-1']/tbody/tr/td[@class ='form col_form']/div/a[@href]").__getattribute__('class')
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'class'

Comment: You have to edit the original post when you want change something in the post. If you want to leave a comment against the answer, click on `add comment` and then provide your comment.